# Why does semantic ui hide content in angular ng-include partials?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, semantic-ui

I *must* be doing something wrong, but I can't seem to figure it out. I'm not a front-end guy, but I've been experimenting with angular and semantic trying to re-do the front-end of an application.

So anyways, the paragraphs in my partial (as well as forms, and other things) are being hidden for some reason.

Here is the index page:

```
<body class="pushable">
    <!-- Body/Background content. Placed as a child to avoid content overlap -->

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div ng-include="'shared/sidebar/sidebarView.html'"></div>

    <!-- Content Pusher for Semantic/Sidebar -->
    <div class="pusher">
        <!-- This is a full-page backgorund pattern I created. Stays fixed on the entire page and content is over it-->
        <div class="main-content"></div>

        <!-- Navbar/Title Menu -->
        <div ng-include="'shared/navbar/navbarView.html'"></div>

        <!-- Location of current View Partial -->
        <div ng-view class="main-view"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is the partial:

```
<div class="ui page grid">
    <div class="ui horizontal divider"></div>

    <div class="ui row segment">
        <div class="ui row">
            <div class="center aligned column">
                <h1>
                    <i class="database icon"></i>
                    Environment Definitions
                </h1>

                <p>
                    Not appearing
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ui row">
            <div class="center aligned column">
                <h1>
                    Yes
                </h1>

                <p>
                    No
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is a screenshot of the result (I whited out some content in the navbar just because):

[image: Screenshot]

Maybe the issue is my fundamental understanding of semantics grid, but their website hasn't helped me out much. In all honesty I haven't had the time to sit down and really scour through the documentation, so I was hoping for some brief feedback or a solid overview here. Any info helps.

Edit. @NewDev recommended that I remove the partial and paste the content from the partial into the index file. Here is the result:

[image: Second screenshot]

Comment: Is your page online ? Because your html seems ok...

Comment: Unfortunately no. Its an internal application, so I don't have a way to push it out. I could put the page up myself but it would take some time configuring a server and whatnot. Maybe I should put together a plunker or something, but that will have to wait until after work.

I agree though, I think the HTML is right. Thats why I'm so confused.

Comment: does it work with semantic if it's not inside a partial?

Comment: Sorry can't help... Check if some of your CSS class have a fixed height, could be the issue

Comment: Nope, I have never used fix height. The application is still small so I can gaurantee that. @NewDev, great idea, let me replace the ng-include with the code from the partial. Will update the question in like 3 minutes with the result.

Comment: @NewDev no luck with replacing the partial. Could it be something with my configuration? Maybe I have a corrupted version of semantic?

Answer (score 1):

The only difference (AFAIK) between the stuff that appears and doesn't is the p tag, which might be messing up how semantic's grid system.